# Pausing javascript timer when scroll off the screen

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code timer that I borrowed from the internet.  The code basically updates some text every 5 seconds.  This text is located in the header of the webpage.  When the user scrolls down so the text is no longer visible, the text continues to update.  How can I modify this code so when the user scrolls so the text is no longer visible, the javascript timer pauses?  Then, when the user scrolls back so the text is visible again, the timer resumes.

Thanks in advance!

```
<h1 id="title-switcher" value="0">One</h1>
        

<script>
function Counter(elem, delay) {
  var value = parseInt(elem.getAttribute("value"), 10);
  var interval;

  var titles = [
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four",
    "Five"
  ];

  function updateDisplay(value) {
    elem.innerHTML = value;
  }

  function run() {
    value += 1;
    if (value == titles.length) value = 0;

    elem.setAttribute("value", value);
    updateDisplay(titles[value]);
  }

  function start() {
    interval = window.setInterval(run, delay);
  }

  // exports
  // This actually creates a function that our counter can call
  // you'll see it used below.
  //
  // The other functions above cannot be accessed from outside
  // this function.
  this.start = start;
}

var elem = document.getElementById("title-switcher");

counter = new Counter(elem, 5000);
counter.start();


</script>
```

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/check-if-an-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport/ Demo: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/sample/dom/event/visible-viewport/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this code at this site: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/check-if-an-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport/.
(Only works if you click full page).

```js
function isInViewport(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)

    );
}


const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    const messageText = isInViewport(box) ?
        'The box is visible in the viewport' :
        'The box is not visible in the viewport';

    message.textContent = messageText;

}, {
    passive: true
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    height: 10000px;
    width: 10000px;
    background-color: #F0DB4F;
}

#message {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #111;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 1;

}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 2px #111;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 300px;
    left: 100px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Check if an element is visible in the viewport</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-viewport.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div id="message">Please scroll to check if the box is visible</div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This article explains two ways of finding what you need: https://usefulangle.com/post/113/javascript-detecting-element-visible-during-scroll

You can either calculate the position of the element and compare it to the page height every time there's a [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event). But this seems to be worse than using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IntersectionObserver` to watch the element is in the viewport and set a flag to keep counting or not.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("title-switcher");

function Counter(elem, delay) {
  var value = parseInt(elem.getAttribute("value"), 10);
  var interval;
  let keepCounting = true;
  var titles = [
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four",
    "Five"
  ];

  function updateDisplay(value) {
    elem.innerHTML = value;
  }

  function run() {
    if (!keepCounting) return;
    value += 1;
    if (value == titles.length) value = 0;

    elem.setAttribute("value", value);
    updateDisplay(titles[value]);
  }

  function start() {
    interval = window.setInterval(run, delay);
    const obsr = new IntersectionObserver((entry) => {
      console.log(entry[0].isIntersecting ? "yes" : "no")
      keepCounting = entry[0].isIntersecting;
    }, options);
    obsr.observe(elem);
  }

  // exports
  // This actually creates a function that our counter can call
  // you'll see it used below.
  //
  // The other functions above cannot be accessed from outside
  // this function.
  this.start = start;
}



const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0.1
}

counter = new Counter(elem, 1000);
counter.start();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 10000px;
  background-color: #F0DB4F;
}

#title-switcher {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 2px #111;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 600px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title-switcher" value="0">One</h1>
```

Comment: Eldar, this was exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly!  Thank you!!!